# Setting H20 Dependency in Intellij and run on spark-submit

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, h2o

I want to launch a jar on spark that use h20 libraries. I created a scala project on intellij and added a package com.hw inside src/scala. Then I wrote a simple Scala program.

Here is the file sbt

```
name := "h20prova"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.12.1"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
"org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "1.5.1",
"ai.h2o"%"sparkling-water-core_2.11"%"2.1.9")
```

The project can see its library without any problem.

I created an artifact specifying the main class com.hw.h20try and builded the artifact succesfully.

Then i launched the script on spark using this command

```
spark-submit --class "com.hw.h20try" h20prova.jar
```

and got the following error

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hw.h20try
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:229)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:695)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:187)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:212)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:126)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

I am pretty sure it's a dependency problem because I had a similar problem using Java and i solved it adding the compiled jar to the artifact build. But I cannot seem to recreate what i did with Java on Scala.

There is another way to setup a Scala project and run on Spark in a few minutes?

Comment: UPDATE:In the file MANIFEST.MF in the sbt build project it is stated that com.hw.h20try was not found, but i do not understand why

Answer (score 1):

your scala versions (2.12.1) and the package versions (2.10, 2.11) doesnt match.
And spark is not supported for scala version 2.12.

```
scalaVersion := "2.12.1"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
"org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "1.5.1",
"ai.h2o"%"sparkling-water-core_2.11"%"2.1.9")
```

so your dependency should be something like this (if you are choosing scala version 2.11).

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.5"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
"org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "1.5.1",
"ai.h2o"%"sparkling-water-core_2.11"%"2.1.9")
```

And reg the `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hw.h20try` exception make sure you have created a uber jar with the dependency using plugin such as [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly).

run a command `jar -tf h20prova.jar | grep h20try` to check if the class is actually packaged and available in the jar.

Comment: I runned the command on the jar and found those files:
_com/hw/h20try$.class_, 
_com/hw/h20try.class_, 
_src/main/scala/com/hw/h20try.scala_ 
but still got the **ClassNotFoundException**